# 500 Can't connect to url with lwp in perl

Tags: json, perl

I'm trying to parse some json data with the fandom wikia API. When I browse to [my marvel.fandom.com/api request](https://marvel.fandom.com/api.php?action=query&titles=Uncanny%20X-Men%20Vol%201%20171&format=json) I get following JSON output: `{"batchcomplete":"","query":{"pages":{"45910":{"pageid":45910,"ns":0,"title":"Uncanny X-Men Vol 1 171"}}}}`

Nothing to fancy to begin with and running it through a JSON parser online gives following output:

```
{
   "batchcomplete":"",
   "query":{
      "pages":{
         "45910":{
            "pageid":45910,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Uncanny X-Men Vol 1 171"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

which seems to be ok as far as I can see

I want to get the pageid for several other requests but I can't seem to get the same output through Perl.
The script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

my $url = "https://marvel.fandom.com/api.php?action=query&titles=Uncanny%20X-Men%20Vol%201%20171&format=json";

my $json = getprint( $url);
die "Could not get $url!" unless defined $json;

my $decoded_json = decode_json($json);
print Dumper($decoded_json);
```

but this gives following error:

```
Could not get https://marvel.fandom.com/api.php?action=query&titles=Uncanny%20X-Men%20Vol%201%20171&format=json! at ./marvelScraper.pl line 11.
```

When I change the get to getprint for some extra info, I get this:

```
500 Can't connect to marvel.fandom.com:443 
<URL:https://marvel.fandom.com/api.php?action=query&titles=Uncanny%20X-Men%20Vol%201%20171&format=json>
malformed JSON string, neither tag, array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "(end of string)") at ./script.pl line 13.
```

I tried this on another computer and still get the same errors.

The versions of `LWP::Simple` and `LWP::Protocol::https`

```
/usr/bin/perl -MLWP::Simple -E'say $LWP::Simple::VERSION'
6.15
/usr/bin/perl -MLWP::Protocol::https -E'say $LWP::Protocol::https::VERSION'
6.09
```

Appearantly it has something to do with the Bash Ubuntu on Windows since on a Ubuntu 18.04 I get (with the same script) following response:

```
JSON text must be an object or array (but found number, string, true, false or null, use allow_nonref to allow this) at ./test.pl line 13.
{"batchcomplete":"","query":{"pages":{"45910":{"pageid":45910,"ns":0,"title":"Uncanny X-Men Vol 1 171"}}}}
```

Comment: It works for me if I replace `getprint` with `get`. The `getprint` function does not return JSON content, rather it returns the status code of the request.

Comment: Code works fine -- gets and prints data, but `$decoded_json` will hold [200](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Simple#getstore) indicating success. Perhaps you intended to use `get` instead to obtain data into a variable. One possibility that you came across [500 Internal Server Error](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) at the moment of test.

Comment: That's weird, it still doesn't work for me. The get function just gives me Could not get https://marvel.fandom.com/api.php?action=query&titles=Uncanny%20X-Men%20Vol%201%20171&format=json! at ./script.pl line 11

Comment: @HåkonHægland could it be a question of different Perl versions or something like that?

Comment: Please [edit] to provide a [mre] and respond to the comments you have received, and this will be eligible for reopening.

Comment: @tripleee But I responded to the comments yesterday and the question is still closed? Also, there is a reproducible example in the question. I even tried it on another computer and it still doesn't work

Comment: @tripleee I edited the question, is it possible now to reopen the question?

Comment: Three different people have attempted to reproduce the problem and are unable to. Either you have gremlins in your network, or you are doing something you are not showing us in the question.

Comment: Maybe add information about which version of LWP::Simple you are using if you are suspecting a version compatibility problem; but I find that hard to imagine.

Comment: It seems most likely to me that you don't have [LWP::Protocol::https](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Protocol::https) installed. What do you see if you run `/usr/bin/perl -MLWP::Protocol::https -E'say $LWP::Protocol::https::VERSION'`?

Comment: Oh, and changing to `getprint()` isn't giving you any further information. `getprint()` returns the HTTP response code (which is 500 here). So the "malformed JSON" error you get is caused by passing that integer (which is invalid JSON) to `decode_json()`.

Comment: @DaveCross added the information. I wouldn't know what I do different than the other guys other than that I use the bash shell on Windows maybe?

Comment: Does "Bash Ubuntu" mean WSL? Please still [edit] to clarify that detail.

Comment: @tripleee It seems there is a difference between running the script on an Ubuntu 18.04 and running it on Bash Ubuntu for Windows (the WSL indeed).. Problem is indeed solved then, although I don't understand why there is a difference between those two to begin with

Comment: @Noosrep: Which version of Ubuntu are you using in WSL?

Comment: @DaveCross It says 18.04 in the question.

Comment: @tripleee: As I read it, it says it works on a "real" Ubuntu 18.04, but doesn't on WSL Ubuntu.

Comment: Ah, my bad, probably worth clarifying.

Comment: I'm going to rewrite the question because now there's just too much irrelevant information. It was 16.04 in WSL but I'm running a release upgrade to see if that will solve the problem but started it before I saw the comments

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the very same script works from my `Bash Ubuntu on Windows` with the `get()` command instead of the `getprint()` you gave after editing your question.

```
orabig@Windows:~/DEV$ ./so.pl
$VAR1 = {
          'query' => {
                       'pages' => {
                                    '45910' => {
                                                 'pageid' => 45910,
                                                 'ns' => 0,
                                                 'title' => 'Uncanny X-Men Vol 1 171'
                                               }
                                  }
                     },
          'batchcomplete' => ''
        };
```

So maybe you have another issue that has nothing to do with Perl or Ubuntu.

Can you try this for example ?

```
curl -v 'https://marvel.fandom.com/api.php?action=query&titles=Uncanny%20X-Men%20Vol%201%20171&format=json'
```

Maybe you just hit the site too much, and the 500 error is just a result of some anti-leech protection ?